# User content database

Tags: plugins, database, login, plugin-contact-form-7

I am trying to set up a login where in each users profile they can add their CV and details. These details and CV will then be shown in a page that can be seen by anyone. The user has the option to edit its information whenever desired and update the information seen in a public page.

For this goal so far I figured out that I need the TML plugin for the login, then I have been trying with Contact Form 7 and Contact Form DB to make the database that gathers the information from the Contact Form7. The problem is connect the profile or a contact form to the user logged in without having to force the user to constantly add a new contact form to the website.

Can anyone point me any headers? Plugins I should use? Is this possible to set up with plugins? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience, I can say that with contact form 7 plugin it will require lot of customization to achieve what you have mentioned. I will suggest to use [BuddyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/) plugin with [BuddyPress Docs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-docs/)

BuddyPress will provide you profile with ability to edit from front end. Also, you can add different fields to profile from backend **Users > Profile Fields**. By default BuddyPress provides ability to add few basic fields to profile. For advance options you can use [Buddypress Xprofile Custom Fields Type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-xprofile-custom-fields-type/) plugin.

I tried these just to share some screenshots with you. Below you will see how the the profile page looks by default with WordPress **Twenty Thirteen** theme.

[image]

Below is how Docs tab will appear by default with WordPress **Twenty Thirteen** theme.

[image]

Comment: So, would I be able to use each users profile information to be displayed in a public page? The idea is to be kind a portfolio page with each users information for employers to see.

Comment: Yes. If you access your site with `/members` at the end then you will see all list of members on your site.

Comment: Is it possible to split the profile fields into 2? (Example, if I want a profile field for students and another for employers)

Comment: You can use [BP Member Type Generator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-member-type-generator/screenshots/) plugin for that. Eager to know how is it going so far :) ?

Comment: Well, I had no idea how to set that up, so I created two groups - one for students and another for employers. Wow, there are soo many types of plugins! http://splice-creative.co.uk/ -Current state. Many thanks for the help so far! Would I be able to create different pages where you could see the two different types of members? (Example - Employers could go to a students page to see all the students informations and the same with Students seeing all the job offers) ?

Comment: I see. Looks great so far. Yes, WordPress has many plugins and highly extendible :-) For Student and Employer listing how about adding direct custom links in menus like below:

[Students](http://splice-creative.co.uk/groups/students/members/)
[Employers](http://splice-creative.co.uk/groups/employers/members/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the combination of CF7 and CFDB can't solve your problem because CFDB doesn't allow user edit his own entry out of the box (You can read this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-to-database-extension-let-an-user-edit-his-own-entries-csv-autogeneration-more)).

Actually, you don't need two plugins above. TML is enough. TML has a option called Themed profile, let user edit profile from front end. All you need to do is adding custom fields to user profile.

You can do it via custom code or plugins. There are many kind of this on the Internet.

**Edit**

You can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) to add custom field to your site's user profile.

If you prefer coding, [this blog](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) will help you alot.

Comment: So, would I be able to use each users profile information to be displayed in a public page? The idea is to be kind a portfolio page with each users information for employers to see.

Comment: Definitely. WP has two built-in function: `get_the_author_meta()` and `the_author_meta()`. Both take two params: `the_author_meta( $meta_key, $user_id );`. You can use this to get user profile field in your porfilio page.

Comment: You can refer to [this post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) for more code example about user profile.

Comment: But with plugins only, and without code, is it possible? Many thanks for the help btw.

Comment: I don't know any plugin that fit exactly your need.  Maybe BuddyPress, but it bundled with many features ( that you may not need )